# TypeError: ReanimatedModule.installTurboModule is not a function

Tags: react-native

i get the following error when i run my iOS App:

```
TypeError: ReanimatedModule.installTurboModule is not a function. (In 'ReanimatedModule.installTurboModule()', 'ReanimatedModule.installTurboModule' is undefined)
```

Have anyone the same error and know how to fix this?